# Ionic 2 cannot find module 'dgram'

Tags: node.js, ionic2, bonjour

I have installed a template Ionic 2 application and want to add the NPM package `bonjour`

After installing and including the package in my component like this:

```
var Bonjour = require('bonjour');
var bonjour = new Bonjour();
```

The application won't run stating 'cannot find module dgram'

The application has both the bonjour package and bonjour types installed.

**The problem**

The application can't find the module dgram which is located in the @types/node file. The project is running **TS 2.4.2**  and should not need any references to the @types, this should be picked up automatically.

**What have I tried**

I tried including the @types folder anyway in multiple ways, by setting typeroots or types in the ts.config.json file. This didn't change anything.

I tried specifying types :

```
"types": ["node", "bonjour"]
```

I tried reinstalling all node modules and clearing the cache

I tried including a reference path in my component above the require statement:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts" />

var Bonjour = require('bonjour');
var bonjour = new Bonjour();
```

This all did not help. Any ideas on how to make my application load this module properly?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on bonjour@3.5.0

Comment: @JackD See answer below

Comment: did you check your import path?Often the case is with the path.

Comment: Did you make it work? You can try this alternatively. Might work for you: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zeroconf/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package Bonjour has a DatagramPlugin which require dgram to function properly. In Ionic 2 this package is not available. The solution is to use the Native Zeroconf package as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you, I had already found that way! I can't make Zeroconf work yet (it never triggers the watch for any mDns host) but this is another story :)

Answer (score 2):

dgram library is included with node.js since v0.1.99 as seen [here](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_class_dgram_socket).

You will always have dgram defined as long as you use a node version post v0.1.99. Your problem is only with Typescript types.

---

**Make sure you are installing node types with `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and that you are including the es6 lib in your tsconfig.json file.**

If the previous step does not work add this on the top: `import * as dgram from "dgram";`

**If nothing works** you can copy the module definition from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts) export it yourself.

---

**Extra tip:** If you do not trust your `tsconfig.json` for some reason pass the `lib` and `types` argument directly in the tsc command such as: `tsc --lib es6 --types node -p .`

Comment: I tried all your solutions but none of them helped. I also tried changing the Ionic webpack config file but the problem remains

Comment: It must be a problem in your environment.

Comment: Yes, Ionic can't seem to use dgram in browser side code

Comment: So he needs a polyfill.